# RCP: NotHandledException and possibly cached command handlers in workspace folders?

Tags: java, rcp

I found a strange error about a missing command handler in our application when installing a newer release for our customer:

```
org.eclipse.core.commands.NotHandledException: There is no handler to execute for command ...
```

I checked the plugins and everything else and found that the handler is actually there, activated, visible, etc. Now the strange thing: the error can be solved by deleting the user's workspace folders (in addition to the runtime folders that happens when starting with -clean). But I cannot find anything related to the commands or handlers. There is a lot of data about column orders, windows sizes and so on, so I can't just wipe these data away for production.

What cached data may cause this effect?

We're stuck to RCP 3.4 right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue can be solved by removing the file `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs` from the workspace.

The file contains perspective IDs as keys, and a XML structure as values. Removing a single line of this file that refers to a perspective solves the problem for that perspective.

I noticed that the perspectives were referenced by their short name (without the package) before, and with their fully qualified name after the new release. So there must be some side-effect when using the old prefs causing the handlers do not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The only information about handlers would be in the plugin configuration in the application `configuration` folder, but a `-clean` start should rebuild this information. There is no information about handlers in the actual workspace folders.

Comment: That is right, but the clean alone does not solve this issue. I found a better solution that works for me, which i put in here. However, I must admit that I do not understand this effect.